# How to find a included JSP name from a section of a jsp page

Tags: jsp

It is common for all of us to have a JSP page which includes several other jsp pages to display the page.

Is there any tool or plugin to find out the included jsp file name from the displayed page?.

Answer (score 1):

***you should use this method:***

```
    <%
       ...
    getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(request.getServletPath());
    //returns file name and path
       ...
    %>
```

---

```
    <%
    ...
    application.getRealPath(request.getServletPath()); 
    //returns file name and path
    ...
    %>
```

---

```
    <%
    ...
    this.getClass().getName(); 
    //returns the class name
    ...
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Is there any tool or plugin to find out the included jsp file name from the displayed page?
```

No u cant view the `JSP` tags in the browser , as they are compiled in the server